# apply jquery slidetoggle to results coming from a while in php

Tags: php, jquery, css

The following piece of code in php, uses a while statement to output variable **$the_job_id**. For each of the output I want to apply jquery slidetoggle. The problem is that in my code slidetoggle works only for the first output of my while. Not working for the rest. Any idea how i should modify my code in order slidetoggle to work for each of my while outputs?

This is my php code:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("select * from `user_job` where `job_id` IN ($all_saved_job_id) ");

while($run_job = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  $the_job_id = $run_job['job_id']; 

echo"<div id='flip'> PRESS TO SLIDE </div>";

echo"  <div id='panel'>  $the_job_id </div>";

}// end while

?>
```

this is my script :

```
<script> 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
     $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

</script>
```

this is my css :

```
<style>

#flip{
cursor:pointer;
margin-left:100px;
}

#panel{
padding:0px;
display:none;
}       

</style>
```

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique on the page. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` must be unique, otherwise you'll always get the first element in the page with duplicated `id`, so you need to use class instead:

```
echo"<div class='flip'> PRESS TO SLIDE </div>";

echo"  <div class='panel'>  $the_job_id </div>";
```

then you can use `.` to target elements by class name:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Please note that you also need to change your CSS selector using `.` instead of `#` accordingly.

Comment: do I have to change my CSS to .panel and .flip ?

Comment: ok did it, but nothing slides up or down now..any idea what it could be wrong?

Comment: What's your generated HTML markup? Can you post it?

Comment: I don't understand what you means, perhaps you can paste your HTML markup here: http://pastebin.com/ and give me the link

Comment: actually when I run it gives me PRESS TO SLIDE, but when press it, it does not slide down to see the value

Comment: You need to use class instead of `id` like my suggested answer as well as including jQuery and it'll work. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MV3Uw/2/

Comment: I have change everything exactly as you tell me, but still slide not working when click it... when click on PRESS nothing slides up or down :-) is there a possibility the problem caused by my php while statement?

Comment: dear friend thanks for your help... believe it or not the problem was finaly that I was using <div class='flip'> and <div class='panel'> inside the php echo ! This is the reason for not working ;-) Thanks for your time and help.